# Symfony CMF can't load homepage and another pages

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-cmf

all.

I tried to rewrite cmf/simplecmsbundle. I try to learn it but now I have problem.
My pages don't display. I don't know what I should to write.

Pages are in database. My homepage initializer is that same what cmf/simplecmfbundle. My configuration too.

What I get after open browser:

```
[2/2] NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /"

[1/2]ResourceNotFoundException: None of the routers in the chain matched this request
```

What I should check and how?
Anyone can help me?

Paste my code here no sense because is this same what cmf/simplecmfbundle. I think that i did a mistake but I dont know where I should to search.

Comment: Currently there is no way to help you, as we don't know anything. What nodes are in the db, how is cmf routing configured, how does your Page document look? Btw, just writing exactly the same things as simple cms bundle seems strange, as just using it is way easier.

Comment: Thank you for reading my post. I solved this problem by adding route basepaths: ['/cms/simple'] to my config.
But I don't know why I should add this when in cms/simplecmsbundle that there is no. Pase my code here no sense. I copyied all files from https://github.com/symfony-cmf/SimpleCmsBundle and I change the name only ( all class etc ). Maybe you are able to tell me where the configuration knows that basepath (for dynamic router) is "/cms/simple" or in which file/class do this?

Comment: Ok I found it. The CmfCore configuration provides for default cmf_simple_cms so when I change name I have no default config. Thank you for your time.